# search about user orders and sort by date (newest first) with firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i'm have an order table in firebase like this
[image]

and in my iOS app, i want to show the orders for the user which is active and want to sort them by (CreateDate) to show the newest first

i'm using this code ,  it's only show the user orders without sorting by date

```
 if   (Auth.auth().currentUser != nil) {
        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
        if let user = user {
            uid = user.uid

            print("uid = \(uid)")


            // get order details
            let ordersRef = rootRef.child("orders")
            ordersRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "clientuid_status").queryEqual(toValue: "\(uid)_0").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in

                let snabshotvalue = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject]
                let dateorder = snabshotvalue!["orderDate"]
                let tecname = snabshotvalue!["tecname"]
                let theproblem = snabshotvalue!["theproblem"]
                let homeadress = snabshotvalue!["homeadress"]
                let clintlat = snabshotvalue!["clintlat"]
                let clintlong = snabshotvalue!["clintlong"]
                let clintuid = snabshotvalue!["clintuid"]
                let tecuid =  snabshotvalue!["tecuid"]
                let tecToken  = snabshotvalue!["tecToken"]
                let status = snabshotvalue!["status"]
                let servicetable = snabshotvalue!["servicetable"]

                let snashotkey = snapshot.key as String
                print("firstname: \(tecname) ")

                self.dateArray.append(dateorder as? String)
                self.tecnameArray.append(tecname as? String)
                self.problemArray.append(theproblem as? String)
                self.homeadressArray.append(homeadress as? String)
                self.clintlatArray.append(clintlat as? String)
                self.clintlongArray.append(clintlong as? String)
                self.tecuidArray.append(tecuid as? String)
                self.tecTokenArray.append(tecToken as? String)
                self.orderuidArray.append(snashotkey )
                self.clintidArray.append(clintuid as? String)
                self.statusArray.append(status as? String)
                self.servicetableArray.append(servicetable as? String)

                self.getTechRatin(teckUid: tecuid as! String)

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })


            }
```

i'm sent a ticket to firebase support, they told me to use this code :

```
    let orderOrdersByCreatedDate= (ref.child("orders").child(getUid())).queryOrdered(byChild: "createDate").queryLimited(toLast: 1)
```

when i try to use your code, i get this error :
Use of unresolved identifier 'getUid'

i don't know how use getUid()

Comment: Do you want to get user id from firebase?

Comment: I can get it by         let user = Auth.auth().currentUser             uid = user.uid

Answer (score 0):

That last snippet of code is wrong. To sort the orders by `creadeDate` you need:

```
ordersRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "creadeDate").observe(.childAdded, ...
```

But Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property, so that means that you can no longer filter on `clientuid_status` as you do now.

In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. You already seem to have done this with `clientuid_status`, and to allow both filtering on that and ordering on date, you'll expand it to `clientuid_status_creadeDate` and order/filter on that.

For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Comment: thanks,i don't care to filter by clientuid_status, i only want to retrieve the orders which equal to clientuid_status and sort them by createDate without sort by uid or status (note: i write it wrong creadeDate) , so if i write  the code like this why it's not working :
                rootRef.child("orders").queryOrdered(byChild: "createDate").queryEqual(toValue: "\(uid)_0").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in

Comment: Because you're ordering/filtering by `createDate`, and then pass in a UID. If you just want to sort on `createDate` drop the `queryEqual(toValue:` clause: `rootRef.child("orders").queryOrdered(byChild: "createDate").observe(.childAdded`. Note that unless you updated your data, you'll need `creadeDate`.